# can I use multiplication of sets in AMPL?

Tags: ampl

I am trying to write a model for a graph problem. 
I defined a pairwise set for labeling the edges. because I need to find inner product between some edges. More precisely:

Suppose E is the set of edges, I defined :

set N, within E cross E;

for example if E={1,2,3}, N can be :{(2,3),(1,2)}
i.e I need to find inner product between edge 1 and edge 3 and also between edge 1 and edge 2.

No my problem is that I have to related edges to vertices. 
For example suppose V={v1,v2,v3,v4,v5} is the set of vertices. and edge 1 is between v1 and v3 and edge 2 is between v2 and v3.

I need to define another pairwise set for example:
set N, within V cross V;
But I need to determine the set of edges behind that. for example if M={(1,3),(2,3)} I need a third column that determine the first pair is belong to edge 1 and the second belong to edge 2.
how I can do that in AMPL?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
set vertices;
set edgenames;
set edges_with_vertices within edgenames cross vertices cross vertices;
```

such that for any triple in edges_with_vertices the first element is the edge name, and the second and third are the end vertices.